# Shaded pictures on focused item in collection view

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Good afternoon.I want to ask a piece of advice how to implement my idea.I have a collection view with photos.It is a simple collection view

```
 <CollectionView  x:Name="AddCar" ItemsSource="{Binding Types}"      BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                  SelectionMode="None">
                    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                        <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                />
                    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid >
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="120" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Frame CornerRadius="0"  Margin="5,5,5,5" Padding="0" >
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Source}"
                          HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                         BackgroundColor="{Binding CustButtonColor}"/>
                                </Frame>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
```

And I want to make like this

[image]

But I do not understand how make focused item and how make unfocused items shaded.Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a try with **[Xamarin.Forms CarouselView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/interaction#define-visual-states)**, it can layout this easily. And the center item will be the current focused item, not need to select one item to be the current selected item in **CollectionView**.

For example the Xaml code as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:CarouselViewDemos.ViewModels"
             x:Class="CarouselViewDemos.Views.VisualStatesPage"
             Title="CarouselView visual states">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:MonkeysViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                  CurrentItemChanged="CarouselView_CurrentItemChanged"
                  PeekAreaInsets="120">
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="CurrentItem">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="Scale"
                                            Value="1.1" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PreviousItem">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="Opacity"
                                            Value="0.5" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="NextItem">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="Opacity"
                                            Value="0.5" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="DefaultItem">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="Opacity"
                                            Value="0.25" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Frame HasShadow="True"
                           BorderColor="DarkGray"
                           CornerRadius="5"
                           Margin="0"
                           Padding="5"
                           HeightRequest="150"
                           WidthRequest="150"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                        <StackLayout>
                            <!--<Label Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   FontSize="Large"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center" />-->
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" 
                                   Aspect="AspectFill"
                                   HeightRequest="150"
                                   WidthRequest="150"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                            <!--<Label Text="{Binding Location}"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Details}"
                                   FontAttributes="Italic"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   MaxLines="5"
                                   LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />-->
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>

</ContentPage>
```

And in **ContentPage.cs** also can know which one the current item:

```
private void CarouselView_CurrentItemChanged(object sender, CurrentItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Monkey previousItem = e.PreviousItem as Monkey;
    Monkey currentItem = e.CurrentItem as Monkey;
}
```

Then the effect as follows:

[image]

Above sampel code based on [this official sample projet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-carouselviewdemos/).